# errror Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setToAddresses(List<String>) fromthetype List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>.Can someonehelp?

Tags: apex

public with sharing class CStatusEmailNotification {

```
public Static final String CG_ORGWIDE_EMAILADDRESS = Label.CG_OrderEmailAddress_OrgWide;

public class CG_OrderInvocableWrapper{
    @invocableVariable(label='Event Name') //email template developerName
    public string eventName;
    @invocableVariable(label='Order Id') // order id
    public Id orderId;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='CG_OrderStatusEmailNotification' description='sends an email when order submitted/shipped')
public static void  sendEmailNotification(List<CG_OrderInvocableWrapper> orderWrapper) { 
 
    try{
        Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> orderAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<ccrz__E_Order__c> orders = new List<ccrz__E_Order__c>();
        Map<Id,ccrz__E_Order__c> ordersMap = new Map<Id,ccrz__E_Order__c>();

        //fetch email template details                
        EmailTemplate templateData = [Select Id,DeveloperName,Subject,Body FROM EmailTemplate
                                                    WHERE DeveloperName = :orderWrapper[0].eventName LIMIT 1];
                                                    
       

        //fetch org-wide email address details
        OrgWideEmailAddress oweAddress = [select id, Address, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress
                                                        Where Address =: CG_ORGWIDE_EMAILADDRESS limit 1];
       
        //loop through all order wrappers and collect order ids
        for(CG_OrderInvocableWrapper orderWrap : orderWrapper){
            orderIds.add(orderWrap.orderId);
        }

        // Fetch buyer and account information from order
      
        for(ccrz__E_Order__c order : [Select Id,ccrz__BuyerEmail__c,ccrz__Account__c,ccrz__Account__r.CG_Account_Id__c,ccrz__User__c,ccrz__Account__r.CG_CSR_Only__c
                                                from ccrz__E_Order__c WHERE Id IN :orderIds]) {
            ordersMap.put(order.Id,order);//orders Map        
            orderAccountIds.add(order.ccrz__Account__c);
        }          
      

        //fetch account team member details
        Map<Id,Set<Id>> accountIdCSRIdsMap = new Map<Id,Set<Id>>();
        Set<Id> csrIds ;
        system.debug('##logLevel');
        List<AccountTeamMember> accountTeamMembers = [Select Id,UserId,AccountId,user.email from AccountTeamMember
                                                            WHERE AccountId IN :orderAccountIds];
        List<string> emailList = new list<string>();
        if(!accountTeamMembers.isEmpty()) {
            for(AccountTeamMember aTeamMember : accountTeamMembers) {
                emailList.add(aTeamMember.user.email);
                csrIds = new Set<Id>();                    
                //if account id already exist in map then get corresponding CSRs under that account
                if(!accountIdCSRIdsMap.keySet().isEmpty() && accountIdCSRIdsMap.containsKey(aTeamMember.AccountId)) {
                    csrIds = accountIdCSRIdsMap.get(aTeamMember.AccountId);
                    csrIds.add(aTeamMember.UserId);
                    accountIdCSRIdsMap.put(aTeamMember.AccountId,csrIds);
                } else{
                    csrIds.add(aTeamMember.UserId);
                    accountIdCSRIdsMap.put(aTeamMember.AccountId,csrIds);
                }
            } 
        }string[] emailArray = new string[emailList];
        
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailsToBeSent = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        
        
         system.debug('##emailsToBeSent'+emailsToBeSent);
        //Create email instances
        if(templateData != null) {
            emailsToBeSent = createEmailInstances(templateData.Id,oweAddress,ordersMap,accountIdCSRIdsMap); 
            
       }
              
        //send email
        if(!emailsToBeSent.isEmpty()) {
            emailsToBeSent.setToAddresses(emailList); ---Getting Error
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(emailsToBeSent);
           
        }       
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `emailsToBeSent` is a list of `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`. So you cannot set `setToAddresses` to a list.

`setToAddresses` is part of `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailMessage = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
emailMessage.setToAddresses()
```

So you need to set to addresses to each instance of `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`, like shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I see you are trying to use method "setToAddresses" on List of SingleEmailMessages. You will be able to use it on a single record of SingleEmailMessage. On List of any type, we can use methods applicable only for a List. For e.g., clear(), add(), etc.